# When using flame/audioplayers, how to stop audios from AudioCache?

Tags: flutter, flame

When using `AudioCache` to play local assets, it has a play method:

```
AudioCache audioPlayer = AudioCache();
await audioPlayer.play('alert_tone.mp3');
```

But there is no stop method. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `AudioCache` methods that start an audio return an instance of the `AudioPlayer` used (can be a brand new one or the `fixedPlayer` one).

You can use that return value to stop it:

```
AudioCache cache = AudioCache();
AudioPlayer player = await cache.play('alert_tone.mp3');

// ...

await player.stop();
```

Or to use any other controls provided by `audioplayers`.

Comment: I would recommend to add `await` to stop: `await player.stop();`.

Comment: The method 'play' isn't defined for the type 'AudioCache'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'play'.dartundefined_method